# Scheme union two lists

Tags: scheme

I am writing a scheme program that takes two lists and displays the union of the lists. This is my code.

```
(define (union a b)
  (cond ((null? b) a)
        ((element? (car b) a)
         (union a (cdr b)))
        (else (union (cons (car b) a) (cdr b)))))
```

When I go to call the method using `(union '(1 2 3) '(2 4 2))`I get an error that reads

```
Exception: variable element? is not bound.
```

What am I doing wrong when I call the method? Thank you.

Comment: `element?` is not primitive in any Scheme report. There are `member` (`equal?`), `memv` (`eqv?`),  and `memq` (`eq?`). For numbers `memv` is the most effiecent, while `member` will work on more data types and make it more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only means that definition of "element?" is not found. Replacing it with "member" (a built-in function in Racket) makes it work:

```
(define (union a b)
  (cond ((null? b) a)
        ((member (car b) a)
         (union a (cdr b)))
        (else (union (cons (car b) a) (cdr b)))))

(union '(1 2 3) '(2 4 2))
```

Output:

```
'(4 1 2 3)
```