# Creating a Union function in Racket

Tags: recursion, racket, unions

I'm trying to create a function in Racket that will read two lists and create a union of the elements in the two sets. This is the code I created to try and emulate this function:

```
(define (union set1 set2)
  (define unilst '())
  (letrec ([build (lambda (build1 build2 lst)
      (define a '())
      (define b '())
      (cond[(equal? build1 '()) 0]
           [(equal? build2 '()) 0]
           [else (set! a (first build1)) (set! b (first build2))
                 (cond
                      [(= a b) (set! lst (cons lst a))]
                      [else (set! lst (cons b lst))
                            (set! lst (cons a lst))])
                            (set! lst (cons (build (rest build1) (rest build2) lst) lst))])
                             lst)])+
    (set! unilst (build set1 set2 '()))
    unilst))
```

But the output I receive is:
`((((3 4 2 3 1 2) 3 4 2 3 1 2) 2 3 1 2) 1 2)`

Should I handle my recursion differently? Or is there something I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Step 1: don't use `set!`. Forget that you ever heard of assignment.

Comment: I take a more pragmatic view about side effects, but yeah, there's no reason to use `set!` in that.

Comment: @molbdnilo should I stick to cons then?

Comment: You should not only stick to `cons`, you should also study in greater detail what it means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheme union two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353424/scheme-union-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you've tried to write code in a different language but with Scheme syntax.
There is almost never any point in using `set!`.

The union of the sets `s1` and `s2` is

- if `s1` is empty, then `s2`
- if `s2` is empty, then `s1`
- if `(first s1)` is a member of `s2`, then the union of `(rest s1)` and `s2`
- otherwise, add `(first s1)` to the union of `(rest s1)` and `s2`

```
(define (union s1 s2)
  (cond [(empty? s1) s2]
        [(empty? s2) s1]
        [(member (first s1) s2) (union (rest s1) s2)]
        [else (cons (first s1) (union (rest s1) s2))]))
```

Test:

```
> (union '() '())
'()
> (union '() '(1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
> (union '(1 2 3) '())
'(1 2 3)
> (union '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
> (union '(1 2 3) '(4 5 3))
'(1 2 4 5 3)
> (union '(3 2 1) '(4 5 3))
'(2 1 4 5 3)
```

Of course, if the output is supposed to be a set, the inputs must also be sets (i.e. no repeated values).